# Manually install packages into ipykernel NOT with anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook

So I want to avoid using anaconda. How can I download packages into an ipykernel I made? I have the location, I just don't know how to activate ipykernels. I see the option for making a new .ipynb file once I'm within the jupyter API but this doesn't help me add the libraries I want to keep isolated on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install packages inside jupyter note book by

```
!pip install pandas("Your package name")
```

in a cell and run it